# вложенные комментарии в laravel 5

Tags: laravel

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите как быть с вложенными комментариями в laravel.
Комментарии хранятся ввиде :

```
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('article_id'); //здесь будет хранится id статьи (slug)
    $table->text('content');
    $table->string('author');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->boolean('public')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
```

для ответа на комментарий будет создаваться новая запись, в отличае от комментария с поле вместо article_id будет вносится id комментария на который это ответ. Подскажите как быть с выводом.

```
     $comment = Comments::where('article_id', '=', $slug)->get();
//так я получаю комментарии
     return view($post->layout, compact('post', 'tag', 'comment'));
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Можно создать поле parent_id и связь будет выглядеть так

```
public function Subсomments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comments::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function Parent() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Comments::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

или использовать более гибкую схему 
[NESTED-SETS](https://cartalyst.com/manual/nested-sets/3.0), [laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset), [baum (тоже nestedset)](https://github.com/etrepat/baum)
 и другие пакеты nested set.